# Unity3D gameObject Color Change?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i have 2 Materials on one gameObject and i want to change the color of the 2. with a c# script

But this script only change the 1. one and i want to change the 2.

Kind regards

```
rayHit.collider.gameObject.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material.color = Color.black;
```

Comment: [GetComponents](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.GetComponents.html)

Comment: rayHit.collider.gameObject.GetComponents<MeshRenderer>().material.color = Color.black; doesnt work because if i use GetComponents it cant find the material

Comment: Mesh colliders are invisible so don't have a colour.  It looks like you want to change the material colour but you don't say how the objects are organised; you can only have one meshrenderer per gameobject.

Comment: i have a tree with 2 materials, i dont know if its allowed but here is a picture https://ibb.co/hYdwXpT // i want to change the Bark color with the Script

Comment: Look at the API reference provided by Unity.  Notice the `materials` property of the [`MeshRenderer`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MeshRenderer.html) component.  That's where to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material`, you change the first material.
You need to use `GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().materials` to get all materials of your `MeshRenderer` in an array.

So if you want to modify the second material, you need to modify the index 1 of the materials array like that :

`rayHit.collider.gameObject.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().materials[1].color = Color.black;`